# Customize parameters to Azure Data Factory ARM Templates

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-rm-template

I have an Data Factory that produces an ARM template and has a corresponding CI/CD pipeline associated with it to move it to a different environment.  The problem that I have is that the ARM template that it generates has over 256 parameters in it, so it cannot be used.  Out of the 300 parameters that it generates I only need about 20 of them.

After reading and researching I found out that you can put an arm-template-parameters-definition.json file in the root of the Source Control system and it will generate only the parameters that are specified in there.  When I create an empty file it generates a template parameter file with only about a dozen or so parameters, for the SecureString parameters.  In addition to these parameters there is another handful of parameters that I want to add, but I can't seem to get the syntax correct for them.

There are 2 types of parameters that want to be able to add a trigger and a linked service.

Below is the JSON for the linkedService that I want to customize.  I want to customize the resourceGroupName property below

```
{
    "name": "[concat(parameters('factoryName'), '/OscDataLake')]",
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedServices",
    "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
    "properties": {
                    "annotations": [],
                    "type": "AzureDataLakeStore",
                    "typeProperties": {
                                    "dataLakeStoreUri": "https://someplace.azuredatalakestore.net/webhdfs/v1",
                                    "tenant": "12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012",
                                    "subscriptionId": "12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012",
                                    "resourceGroupName": "osc-dev"
                    }
    },
    "dependsOn": []
},
```

Below is the trigger that I want to customize.  I want to change the scope property of the trigger below:

```
{
    "name": "[concat(parameters('factoryName'), '/EventMonthlyFileTrigger')]",
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/triggers",
    "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
    "properties": {
                    "annotations": [],
                    "runtimeState": "Started",
                    "pipelines": [
                                    {
                                                    "pipelineReference": {
                                                                    "referenceName": "EventMonthly_Pipeline",
                                                                    "type": "PipelineReference"
                                                    },
                                                    "parameters": {
                                                                    "FileName": "@triggerBody().fileName"
                                                    }
                                    }
                    ],
                    "type": "BlobEventsTrigger",
                    "typeProperties": {
                                    "blobPathBeginsWith": "/batch/",
                                    "blobPathEndsWith": "eventmonthly.csv",
                                    "scope": "/subscriptions/12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012/resourceGroups/os-App-Rg-01/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/appdevelopment",
                                    "events": [
                                                    "Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated"
                                    ]
                    }
    },
    "dependsOn": [
                    "[concat(variables('factoryId'), '/pipelines/EventMonthly_Pipeline')]"
    ]
}
```

Can someone help me with the correct syntax for the ARM Parameter Template file to customize these.

Comment: Is'nt this the duplicate of your already asked question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54755940/how-to-get-around-azure-data-factory-arm-template-parameter-limits

Comment: It is along the same lines but I didn’t get an answer to the other one and this is asking for how to deal with the syntax of the parameter template file. The previous one was asking how to deal with too many parameters which I found the solution for.

Comment: So you need to know how to change the value of scope ? and resource group ? I can't seem to understand what you need

Comment: I need to understand the arm-template-parameters-definition.json format required to make the data factory only produce those 2 parameters when it generates the parameter file